# Como criar metadados (dados personalizados) numa rota Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas

Gostaria de saber se no Laravel, além das informações que já tenho numa rota, como o `name`, `action` ou `uri`, existe alguma forma de definir metadados.

Por exemplo:

```
Route::get('/', [
  'uses'      => 'HomeController@getIndex',
  'as'        => 'home',
  '__title__' => 'Página inicial'
]);
```

No Laravel, existe alguma foram de recuperar esse valor de `__title__` que defini nessa rota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe, você pode capturar usando `$request->route()->getAction()['__title__']`.

Por exemplo

```
class HomeController 
{
    public getIndex(Request $request) {
        $title = $request->route()->getAction()['__title__'];

        return view('sua_view', [
          'title' => $title,
          'dados' => $model
        ]);
    }
}
```